# How can I install different icons?

Tags: icons, themes, appearance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get and install more themes, icons, and pointers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116/how-do-i-get-and-install-more-themes-icons-and-pointers)

I often find myself seeing new icons but I am unable to install them.

How do you install icons on Ubuntu? Can someone break down the process for me?

Comment: Icons for what? Do you mean icons used in themes? Or application icons? Which flavor of desktop?

Comment: icons used for themes, gnome desktop :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drag and drop the theme package in the Appearance Preferences window
 (`System->Preferences->Appearance`) **Theme** tab.
[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I had look trough other threads here and finally found this one. It was helpful for me

Answer (score 4):

To add a new icon theme, copy them into the hidden directory (control+h in nautilus to show hidden files) `.icons` in your home directory.

You should then be able to select them from Appearance Preferences.

If you don't have a `~/.icons` directory, just create one.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to change an individual icon you should do the following:

- Download a *.png* image
- Right click the icon you want to change
- Go to *Preferences* and then click on the little image window on the upper left.

  It will open a dialog where you can select the icon you wish to substitute for the old one.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It would be great if you could add some screenshots to make it easier to follow your instructions.