# How do I install a new icon set?

Tags: 11.10, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install different icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2057/how-can-i-install-different-icons)

> I am looking for new look to Ubuntu Desktop.

I've read about something called the Faenza icons but I dont know where to download these or how to install these.

Can anyone provide me some step-by-step instructions please?

Comment: new look to desktop , some 3d effects , icon's themes etc

Comment: updated , now ok ? plz edit if u think its not ok ,

Comment: Although it's for 10.04 it applies here as well look at the second answer since the appearence settings have changed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2057/how-can-i-install-new-different-icons-for-the-gnome-desktop-in-ubuntu-10-04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK,

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal
2. Add repository of Faenza (`ppa:tiheum/equinox`) by running following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
   ```
3. Update available software information by running following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Run `sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme` to install the icon sets
5. You need a tool for changing icon set. You can use Gnome Tweak Tool:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
6. Launch ***Advanced Settings***
7. Select `Theme` from the right list and then change `Icon theme:` to any Faenza theme

Answer (score 3):

Faenza is best installed from its official PPA. This ensures that you receive the latest updates and fixes automatically.

Firstly open a terminal to add the Faenza icon PPA to your Software Sources;

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox`

Then refresh your sources;

`sudo apt-get update`

Then open the Ubuntu Software Centre and search for ‘faenza-icon-theme‘ to install.

Source : [Omg! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/faenza-icon-theme-updated-adds-handful-of-new-icons/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Faenza?content=128143) to download and install Faenza icons set that you asked for.

It can be installed in two ways:

1. By downloading the tar.gz file, or
2. by adding PPA repository.

Just refer "Installation" in the description.

You can also find more stuffs to change the look and feel of Ubuntu in this [website](http://gnome-look.org/).

Comment: Download the tar file and place it where..?