# How do I use the Equinox theme?

Tags: themes

I installed the Equinox themes in 11.10 but I'm not quite sure how to use them; I installed Gtk-ChTheme and they're all in there, but nothing appears to happen when I press apply and I don't see the themes in the appearance menu...

What am I doing wrong? I want to apply the theme and icon set. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more information on where you got the theme from and how you installed it?

Comment: Also, you may want to take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/69148/18612) on another question and let us know if it solves the problem for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a tool for GTK+2 in a GTK+3 setting. To change the theme at Ubuntu 11.04 and later, you will need [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool) instead.

[image]