# How to install a gnome shell theme?

Tags: unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get and install more themes, icons, and pointers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116/how-do-i-get-and-install-more-themes-icons-and-pointers)

I switched from Unity to Gnome 3.4 but I'd like to tweak my desktop a bit. I want to use a gnome shell theme but the gnome tweak tool won't allow me to modify the gnome shell themes. I've read somewhere that if I reinstall the gnome-shell then it would conflict with Unity and I wouldn't be able to safely use Unity anymore. Is there a way to change the theme without reinstalling the gnome-shell?

Comment: r u sure that u have **gtk+3** theme?

Answer (score 0):

gnome tweak tool will install both gnome3 and gnome2 fallback
and install gnome-tweak-tool

also for themes download from [gnome look](http://gnome-look.org)
and extract the files on directory ~/.themes (if not exist just create it )

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean in your first paragraph? Are you saying gnome-tweak-tool will work in both GNOME 2 and GNOME 3? What you wrote sounds like it's saying that gnome-tweak-tool will *cause both GNOME 3 and GNOME 2 to be installed, even if they weren't before*. (Also, please note that GNOME Fallback is actually GNOME 3, not GNOME 2. By design, it looks similar to GNOME 2, but it is part of the GNOME 3 desktop environment and it uses version 3 libraries rather than version 2 libraries.)