# How do I fix gnome shell themes?

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install shell-themes using gnome-tweak-tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194791/cannot-install-shell-themes-using-gnome-tweak-tool)

This is my fifth full format and install of Ubuntu in under a month.  I finally have my Gnome 3 desktop working again, but again, the Gnome shell themes is not select-able.  I have asked the question of how to fix this common issue before, but I have seen no positive resolution.  Does anybody know of a simple fix?  This is a common issue and I have seen hundreds of postings related to it, but other users only seem to get half-way answers also and it goes unresolved.  Would it be advisable to completely purge Gnome desktop and reinstall? If so how would I do this?  I cannot use any extensions if the shell is not working, so I am desperately seeking resolution for the issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: " I have asked the question of how to fix this common issue before..." Please do not post the same question multiple times. Instead, invest some time in the site and obtain reputation to start a bounty as per the [faq#bounty].

Comment: again, I have done that and cannot find a positive resolution.  If there was half as much effort put into the answers as there is policing these posts then it would be resolved already.

Comment: It is common for users to put up bounties to try to attract more experienced users. [I have done so](http://askubuntu.com/users/54298/obsessivesso?tab=bounties&sort=offered), as well as many other users. You must remember that the users here aren't paid for this, and have commitments outside of Ask Ubuntu. Therefore, you must invest time in the site yourself if you are not getting good answers. I will now cast a closevote as an exact duplicate to your other post. If you oppose this, please explain why they are not duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling gnome desktop with

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-desktop&&sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop
```

?

Answer (score 0):

All gnome shell extensions are here : [Gnome Shell Extensions.](https://extensions.gnome.org/)

You must have an active gnome-shell environment and the gnome-tweak-tool installed.
Goto the page and click the "About" and you will see how you can install them. 
On the search bar you can search for any theme you want. Example : **User themes**

The installation is very easy , just click the light button. You will figure it out.