# How can I install GTK themes on Ubuntu?

Tags: themes, gtk

How can I install themes in ubuntu 12.10 ?

For example, how can I install the following themes on ubuntu:

- [GrayDay](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/GrayDay?content=149310)
- [Elegant+Eggplant](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Elegant+Eggplant?content=153786)

Comment: Or... There is a way if you know the repository. It's a simple matter of just adding the repository and running `sudo apt-get install *theme name*` :) This is the most hassle-free way th

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116/how-do-i-get-and-install-more-themes-icons-and-pointers

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You download it, extract it to `~/.themes`, and you can use ubuntu tweak tool to select the theme. I will guide you through it with the grayday theme you selected in gnome-look.org.

Just a warning, not all themes work nicely under unity.

1. Download grayday, and double-click it in nautilus to open it in the archive manager. You will see a folder called "GrayDay".
2. Drag that folder into your `~/.themes` folder. This is in your home directory. You will have to click "show hidden files" (under view). If you still don't see it, you will have to make the directory in your home folder. Just click make new folder and call it `.themes`.
3. Download ubuntu tweak tool from here. http://ubuntu-tweak.com/
   Just double click the downloaded .deb file and you should be able to install it through the software-center.
4. Once you have it installed, open ubuntu tweak tool and go to "Tweaks" and click theme.
5. Select Grayday in GTK theme and Window theme.

It should work.

Comment: I don't have a ~/.themes... I'm running 13.10.

Comment: @ZeroDivide: Then you will have to make it, like mentioned in the post. Go to your home folder, right click->Create new folder and name it ".themes".

Or, open up your terminal and type: "mkdir ~/.themes".

Comment: "/home/casper" where casper is my user name. Is this directory correct? This folder also include ".fonts", right? Thank.

Comment: That is correct. Put the theme inside /home/casper/.themes

If there is no .themes folder, make one.

Comment: 4 years later, Ubuntu Tweak has become unsupported. I tried to install it by manually installing the package, but it failed in the end. The link you gave us now redirects to some window manager for OS X. Do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 16):

**No extra downloaded third party software is needed.**

For gnome shell, you can install the gnome-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

For Ubuntu unity, you can either install the `gnome-tweak-tool` or you can use the `unity-tweak-tool` to change themes:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Download and extract all themes to your `~/.themes` directory. Run the following command to create this directory:

```
mkdir ~/.themes
```

This directory is hidden, so you must press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> after you open `nautilus` to display hidden files if the directory is not displayed.

Once the theme has been downloaded and extracted to your `~/.themes` directory, open either `gnome-tweak-tool` or `unity-tweak-tool` to select the theme.

Comment: this doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I think I was trying with a theme which didn't have `gtk-2.0` or `gtk-3.0` folders: https://askubuntu.com/questions/854253/how-to-install-a-custom-gtk3-ubuntu-theme-without-having-to-add-a-ppa

Comment: @knocte Yes, I believe it needs at the very least gtk3 for Unity on 14.04+ and I think I heard somebody say something about how it needs to have the css files and that is why some gtk<=2 themes don't work.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 and Unity7 (needed to install `unity-lens-files` package though to run unity-tweak-toll properly).

Comment: @installero Yeah, just a heads up, I assume you got a missing schema error. You can use the `apt-file` command to search for the needed package `sudo apt install apt-file` and `sudo apt-file update` and `apt-file search com.canonical.Unity.FilesLens` .