# How to install the following theme on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: themes, ubuntu-tweak

I wanted to install the following theme (http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?action=content&content=155582) and tried to do it like this ([How can I install GTK themes on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213697/how-can-i-install-themes/213702)), however, there's no .deb file in the archive for step 3. How can I install it now?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/213697

Answer (score 2):

Open the archive and place its contents in '~/.themes'

'.themes' is located in your home folder. It's a hidden folder that you can make visible by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd>.

If you don't have a '.themes' folder; create it.

With this method you are the only user that can use the theme. If you wish to install system-wide use the other answer.

Comment: No such file or directory for 13.10!

Comment: If you don't have a '.themes' folder; create it.

Answer (score 1):

Save the file and open your terminal, run below command:

```
sudo tar xvzf themeFile.tar.gz -C /usr/share/themes/
```

Then check your settings or logoff and login to see changes.