# How to change close button icon in a custom distro using LXDE and icewm?

Tags: lxde, icewm

How do I change the icon of the close tab button on Gedit in a custom distro with LXDE and  icewm as window manager?  Do you know where it resides or how I can change it? Now, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: this is the image showing which button i mean: http://i.imgur.com/1k8kSGM.jpg

Comment: It turns out the files are in the gtk themes folder..specifically the folder "nuoveXT2". For future reference the path is: /usr/share/icons/nuoveXT2 or /usr/share/icons.

Comment: If this is a custom distro, you need to ask on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: No worry, the last comment marked this question as resolved so you can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution but this might give you a clue about what to search for:

http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-notebook-tabs-with-close-button.html

So it seems to be defined by the gtk theme, and the button image must be somewhere in the specific theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change your theme, and you change the recurring objects on your screen, such as close buttons. [UbuntuThemes](http://www.ubuntuthemes.org/) provides, free, a vast number of themes, and you can deconstruct them to see which elements come from where for custom themes, and more [theme change information is available on this board](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213697/how-can-i-install-themes) at [at Ubuntu directly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEyeCandy).

To summarize the steps:

- Make a folder ~/.themes folder (ignore if you already have one -
  check with `cd ~ & ls -al` from a terminal window.
- Download your theme of choice; double-click on it in your file
  manager to have the archive manager open.
- Extract the contents into a folder underneath ~/.themes
- Get the [Ubuntu tweak tool](http://ubuntu-tweak.com): Open the .deb you downloaded, then
  install using the Software Center.
- Launch the Ubuntu tweak tool - go to "Tweaks" and pick your theme.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say i'm using my own distro. Running a lxde with icewm as window manager. Everything is fine except i still can't find where that icon resides, even with your suggestions which i already did before :/

Comment: OK. Is it an Ubuntu-based distro, e.g., Lubuntu? Because, if not, you are far more likely to get a useful answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh well, it's a debian based distro. Thank you i'll look there.