# Customize desktop appearance 14.04

Tags: themes, customization

I'd like to adjust my colors, themes, icons and such.  Windows has a great tool for this and the "myunity" application doesn't seem to be available any longer for 14.04

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu Tweak or [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/)?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak, http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size/59920#59920, http://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity, http://askubuntu.com/questions/213697/how-can-i-install-gtk-themes-on-ubuntu, http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/?global=1&q=gtk+theme&offset=216 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Unity Tweak Tool**

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Also, if you want more options to change colors etc, you can install **Gnome Color Manager**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-manager
```

Comment: thanks it wasn't clear initially that unity tweak did themes  :)

Comment: now I just need to figure out where themes should be stored for Tweak to work!