# How to install a custom GTK3 Ubuntu theme without having to add a PPA?

Tags: unity, themes, gtk3

Adding a PPA is an action that requires trust.

If I haven't read the source code of the repository that is held in the PPA, I shouldn't install a random PPA for security reasons.

Therefore, is there a way to install a theme (I'm interested in a dark one) for Ubuntu 16.04 without adding a PPA? I've already tried to download [this one](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1163247/), and after decompressing the tar.gz and looking that there are no executable files, I've placed it in my ~/.themes folder but `unity-tweak-tool` doesn't see it (maybe this tool is deprecated for this version of ubuntu?).

Comment: That one doesn't look like a properly structured theme; it's just a bunch of .svg files.

Comment: "Adding a PPA is an action that requires trust." and there is a reason not to trust the owner of any PPA that is hosted on launchpad? " and looking that there are no executable files" a --theme-- would need an executable? why? It is a cinnamon theme. So you are using cinnamon? Or did you expect a cinnamon theme to work in -unity-?

Comment: I downloaded it from a page of gtk3 themes, ubuntu uses GTK3

Comment: wrt "executable" I'm of course not saying that a theme needs one, I'm saying that a malicious PPA could contain an executable in their .deb files

Answer (score 2):

You need to download `.zip` of the theme that you want to install. For example [dark theme](https://github.com/chauhankiran/arc-black-ubuntu). Now extract this and you will get named folder.

Place that folder inisde of `~/.themes`. and run the following command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "theme_name"`

Here, `theme_name` should be name of your theme/folder.

Comment: Thanks , that works. But why the theme not loaded on the `gnome-tweak-tool`?

Comment: Have you restarted GTT or rebooted sys.?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04, `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` and Adwaita(dark) is there in the list by default (my initial motivation was to find a dark them for night hacking).

OLD ANSWER:

In the [Gnome-Look](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1163247/) site, I finally found one which linked to a github repo, so I could look inside (to check it only has images and data files, e.g. xml, css, etc) and download it myself.

In particular, I downloaded https://github.com/B00merang-Project/B00merang-Themes/, and copied the `B00merang-Dark` folder to `/usr/share/themes`.

Then installed `unity-tweak-tool`, and chose it with it.