# How do i make it less orange? (ubuntu 16.04 with standard desktop)

Tags: 16.04, unity, gui, personalization

Can i change the colours in ubuntu 16.04 so that selected items become something less awful than orange? So it highlights things in blue or yellow or purple or green, or, pretty much anything except orange?

Comment: Change the theme.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this can be easily changed with the help of a theme. You will have to download the one that one like and add the folder to `~/.themes` and then with a tool like Ubuntu Tweak install it.
There is guide step by step in the answer section of this question:
[How can I install GTK themes on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213697/how-can-i-install-gtk-themes-on-ubuntu)
Regarding ONLY the highlitening color, did you take a look at this: [REPLACE THE ORANGE COLOR IN UBUNTU 11.10 (ACTIVE COLOR)](https://antecblue.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/replace-the-orange-color-in-ubuntu-11-10-active-color/) I haven't tried it myself but I bet it still works.

However there is a more user-friendly way: `sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config` and this is what I think you are looking for. Just open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type that piece of code then run the program with `gtk-theme-config`. With that tool you can change just 'Highlight background'. You can change other menus and panels' colors too.

Comment: can i do a custom theme? or change just that one colour on the standard theme?

Comment: I just edited the answer to add some more information.