# How to apply 3rd party themes?

Tags: themes

I was looking for a dark theme to install and came [across this page](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/03/install-trevilla-themes-and-icons-in.html). I followed the instructions to install the Trevilla-Icons and Trevilla-Jmhzone-Dark Theme, but I can't select them on the appearance settings under themes it doesn't show up, Am I going about selecting the theme all wrong? I've never installed themes before so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116/how-do-i-get-and-install-more-themes-icons-and-pointers

I would suggest using Unity Tweak Tool (it's in the repositories).

Comment: It's Ubuntu Tweak, not Unity Tweak. I keep the making the mistake myself >.<

Comment: @Kupiakos there is something known as Unity Tweak Tool that is included in the repositories (I have both and I know what I'm talking about). We already have a question and answer detailing how to install Ubuntu Tweak, so no need to duplicate it here.

Comment: Hrm, ok then. Thanks for the info. I'll take a look at it; I was unaware of its existence. Sorry 'bout that ~,~

Answer (score 0):

After it has installed, you can install something like Ubuntu Tweak to change your theme using these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

After installation, open Ubuntu Tweak, then select the *Tweaks* Menu, then select the *Theme* Menu. The theme should appear under the *Gtk Theme* Menu or another similar menu.

Comment: completely forgot about ubuntu tweak, i was using it not so long ago on zorin, thanks alot

Comment: Please remember to mark an answer as correct if it is ;->