# How to highlight the last active window in the GNOME shell preview

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Is there a way to highlight (with some sort of indicator) the last active window in the Gnome launcher?

Suppose this is my launcher, and I have just used the Terminal. I'm wondering if there is a way to highlight it as the last active one, to differentiate it from the rest of the windows:

[image]

So the result would be something like this:

[image]

<sub>I'm completely new to Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu, so please let me know if this question needs to be edited.</sub>

Comment: @Takkat Thanks! I just added an image. I am in a GNOME3 desktop (not unity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preview is the same as our theme

The appearance of windows in the *Activities* preview from the GNOME shell depends on the theme we have installed. We can not add an additional window frame in this preview. From the default theme *Adwaita* there is then not much difference from an active *vs.* an inactive window. It is hard to spot.

Unfortunately we also do not have much options to change the windows decoration of an installed theme by design. However below are two examples of other themes which both have a better contrast from the active *vs.* inactive windows:

#### Faience

There is not a great difference, but it is a theme many users like. We can see that the active window's title (gnome-tweak-tool) is slightly darker than the titles of the two inactive windows (terminal, firefox).

[image]

#### Esco

This is one of the default themes that comes with the Ubuntu GNOME remix. Here an active window has a blue title bar, and a small blue frame. But this then is at cost of a somewhat more retro design.

[image]

It may take some time until we found a theme we may like. A starting point to look for community contributed themes is [GNOME-LOOK.ORG](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=191) but we may also try to make our own theme if we feel like spending hours customizing. Also see

- [How do I get and install more themes, icons, and pointers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116/how-do-i-get-and-install-more-themes-icons-and-pointers)

Comment: Ah! That's great to know. Should I rephrase the question to reflect that this is about themes?

Comment: I believe the question is o.k. as we do already have a general theme question (see edit).