# Where can I find more Unity themes?

Tags: unity, themes

This might already be answered, but I can't find it.

I am getting a bit bored of the traditional purple feel of unity and I would like something new. Where can I find more Unity themes?

I have already tried synaptic, but could not find anything. I would rather avoid people's personal PPA's.

Comment: IIRC the Launcher, Dash, etc. don't support themes. Only window manager and GTK themes are supported.

Comment: I suggest to try mokka theme.  Also look at noobslab site.

Comment: You can also have a look at [Romix](https://github.com/rohithmadhavan/Romix), a theme I created based on Numix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get and install more themes, icons, and pointers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116/how-do-i-get-and-install-more-themes-icons-and-pointers)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [Themes Collection by NoobsLab](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes?field.series_filter=utopic) PPA has an interesting selection of themes for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu up to 16.04. To add this PPA to your software sources open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install popular themes from the default Ubuntu repositories, like [MBuntu](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/11/mbuntu-macbuntu-1410-transformation.html), which resembles Mac OS X Yosemite, [Numix](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/05/numix-theme-for-ubuntulinux-mintother.html) and several other themes.

Comment: How do I set the theme after installing it?

Comment: To set the Numix theme from ppa:noobslab/themes after installing it with `sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme` install Unity Tweak Tool from the Ubuntu Software Center and in Unity Tweak Tool click Theme icon and under **Available themes** select *Numix*  from the theme list.

Answer (score 6):

you can start with these:

1. [Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/themes-collection-for-ubuntu-1110-unity.html)
2. [Numix](https://numixproject.org/)
3. [Orchis](http://mokaproject.com/orchis-gtk-theme/)

or better use google search

Answer (score 6):

The popular Numix theme has landed in the Ubuntu Software Center starting with Ubuntu 14.04. There is a choice of either the Numix - GTK3 Dark Theme or the Numix - GTK3 Light Theme, either of which costs $3 USD.

Answer (score 5):

You can find many **GTK 3.x Themes** here: http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=167

But you should make sure that you choose the ones which support the right version, e.g. 3.12 for Ubuntu 14.10.

Some examples I've chosen are:

- http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Vertex+-+Theme?content=166318
- http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Zukitwo?content=140562
- http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+%26+Radiance+Colors+Suite?content=165994
- http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/DeLorean%2BDeLorean-Dark?content=167703
- http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Dorian+Theme?content=157200

There is also the **Greybird theme** in Ubuntu Software Center which is one of the most compatible and consistent alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

There's a project called RAVEfinity that makes clean, modern themes. The theme [Ambiance & Radiance Flat Colors](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/download-ambiance-radiance-flat-colors.html) with the icon pack [Vivacious Colors](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/vivacious-colors-gtk-icon-theme.html) is my favourite, and it's what I've been using for months. Their website layout is a bit confusing, so here's their [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kss3Y.png).

p.s. The main reason I made this comment is that RAVEfinity doesn't show up in Google searches for "Ubuntu themes" or "Ubuntu skins", and I think they deserve more publicity. Their work is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

This is Arc GTK theme, for Unity, is the best I've found:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-latest-arc-gtk-theme-ubuntu-16-04

Numix icons look awesome with this theme.

I use this combination: Arc-Darker + Numix-Circle (I moved the launcher to the bottom and made it completely opaque with 38 icon size, use Unity Tweak Tool)

This is how it looks like:
[image]