# How to change system background color 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xfce, colors

I want to change the background color of the windowing system to gray. 
The goal is, that e.g.

- Background color of empty tab in Firefox is gray
- Background color of all the frames in Thunderbird are gray
- Background color of a page in libre office is grey
- Background color of file managers is grey
- ...

In windows there was a very convenient option through Desktop->right click-> properties -> ... .
How do I do this in xubuntu?

edit: here is a picture of the dialog in windows:
[picture colors in windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edKNb.jpg) (you see, that I set the bgcolor to gray)

Comment: Like the answer below says "themes" are the Ubuntu way but I've never deviated from the standard installation of "Ambiance Theme" or whatever it is called. Your question is interesting and I think a screen snapshot from Windows would provide a great visual.

Answer (score 0):

Unix is not Window but you can [get more themes.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520379/where-can-i-find-more-unity-themes/554654) And hopefully, find one that meets your needs.

The Themes Collection by NoobsLab PPA has an interesting selection of themes for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu up to 16.04. To add this PPA to your software sources open the terminal and run the following commands:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
Then you can install popular themes from the Ubuntu Software Center, like MBuntu, which resembles Mac OS X Yosemite, Numix and several other themes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Themes appear to not affect the background color. Even settings inside themerc were not helpful here.